# page url get write when push page on ionic2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

all I'm new on ionic2 and angular2 I want to ask if this method true or not?
I had an array that contains some menu with page property example like this

```
{
"menu" : [
      {"nama" : "My Repair Request","page":"RepairRequestPage","icon":"ios-hammer-outline"},
      {"nama" : "My Front Desk Instruction","page":"FrontDeskinstPage","icon":"ios-desktop-outline"},
      {"nama" : "Amenity Reservation","page":"","icon":"ios-clipboard-outline"},
      {"nama" : "My Delivery","page":"","icon":"ios-cube-outline"}
    ]
}
```

and then i loop to view and give some function :

```
<div>
    <ion-card class="menuCard center_content" *ngFor="let item of list_menu" (click) = 'openMenu(item)'>
      <ion-icon ios="{{item.icon}}" md="{{item.icon}}" ></ion-icon>
      <span>
        {{item.nama}}
      </span>
    </ion-card>
  </div>
```

the function is :

```
openMenu (param : any) {
    this.navCtrl.push(param.page);
  }
```

first that I notice is when the page is pushed there is some link that wrote on URL bar *http://localhost:8100/#/home/repair-request*

I want to ask isn't on angular 2 route had not been running like this I get a bit curious about this can someone explain it to me is it the right one or not...

[[image]]

Comment: Do you want's to change your routes dynamically?

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-updating-the-url-when-pushing-page-on-the-nav-stack/67683/21

Comment: thsk for the responds,
yes i want to change my route dynamically that i got from array that containt object and had attribute key page that specific which page that should be opened , i had been succed to change the page but just a bit curios why at the link bar is not the same as usual like when i declare the page name on controler like this.navbar.pus(homePage);
the with that function homePage is being import to app.module.ts

Sorry if my explanation a bit weird i still dont now how to explainde well and my english is not really good

Comment: Have you updated angular/route in your project?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of the [RouterModule](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule) that will execute our desired routing functionality.

After that, you just pass an array of route objects to either the `forRoot` or `forChild` methods on the **RouterModule**.

Also, make sure you are doing `useHash` to `false` of RouterModule option.

> { useHash: false }

`useHash:` enables the location strategy that uses the URL fragment instead of the history API.

Check the following sample code in your `app.routes.ts`

```
          import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
          import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

          // custom imports
          import { Page1Component } from '../pages/page1/page1.component';
          import { Page2Component } from '../pages/page2/page2.component';
          import { Page3Component } from '../pages/page3/page3.component';


          export const APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(
              [
                  { path: '', redirectTo: '/page1', pathMatch: 'full' },
                  { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component },
                  { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component },
                  { path: 'page3', component: Page3Component}
              ] , {useHash: false});
```

For each route we provide a `path` and the `component` that should be rendered at that path. The empty string for the **HomeComponent's** path means that the HomeComponent will be rendered when there is no URL.

Then, you have simply import our new routing module into the app module.

```
imports: [
 APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER,
 IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
],
```

For more help please check this [link1](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-updating-the-url-when-pushing-page-on-the-nav-stack/67683/21) and [link2](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/angular-2-routing-navigation).

Hopes this will help you!!

Comment: hey santosh i can't use import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; on ionic 2 the error said that [ts] can't find module @angular/router

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ts-cant-find-module-angular-router/57817

Comment: Update your angular/route package please check above link